# Python writing to the last file but not the first one

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

Python doesnt seem to write to my first file but does for the second (and last) one.

Im writing a discord bot that takes the guilds ID and uses them as file names, for each guild I want a json file containing the variables for that specific guild.

Everything was good until I cant find any possible solution to this problem:

```
    Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-13' coro=<twitchGet() done, defined at C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\Python\discord_streambot.py:82> exception=JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\Python\discord_streambot.py", line 87, in twitchGet
    values = await getJsonValues(guild.id)
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\Python\discord_streambot.py", line 79, in getJsonValues
    jsonInfo = json.load(File)
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Now, I luckily know how to read and I can identify that the problem is the **json.load()** function trying to load an empty json file, but my json writing function doesnt seem to have any issue, does anyone have a clue on whats wrong or another way of writing the function? I repeat, the function writes the second(and for now last) file but not the first one

```
def createDefaultFile(id: int):

    writeToFile = {
        'delay' : TIMEDELAY,
        'streamers' : [],
        'textchannel' : None,
    }

    file = Path(str(id)+'.json')

    if file.is_file():
        print('File Exists \n')
    else:
        print('Creating File \n')
        open(str(id)+'.json','a').close()
        with open(str(id) + '.json', 'w', encoding ='utf8') as json_file:
            json.dump(writeToFile, json_file)
```

EDIT:
As requested, line 87 of the discord_streambot.py

```
#Check if there are streamers set
count = 0
for guild in bot.guilds:
    values = await getJsonValues(guild.id)
    for streamer in values['streamers']:
        count += 1
```

getJsonValues function:

```
async def getJsonValues(id: int):
    try:
        File = open(str(id)+'.json','w+')
    except IOError:
        print('Cannot open file')
        return None
    jsonInfo = json.load(File)
    return jsonInfo
```

Comment: I'd love to help. However I don't think I have all the puzzle pieces yet. You said it is `trying to load an empty json file`. Should it not be? Is this being populated somewhere else first? Please provide more detail. Your code around line 87 in `discord_streambot.py` will be necessary to help you (I believe). Glad to help

Comment: The json file shouldn't be empty, it should be loaded with the default parameters in the writeToFile dict, I'll add the code you requested if that means it helps

Comment: Before you call `jsonInfo = json.load(File)` could you `print(File)`? Also, it's not good programming practice to name your variables with the first letter uppercase. It tells people the variable is a class.

Comment: I will implement that practice in the future.
The output is the following:
`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='402169002732027924.json' mode='w+' encoding='cp1252'>`

Answer (score 0):

Please print the contents of your JSON file, I can not be sure without looking at then however I believe that your problem is that the JSON file is empty. Please write this in the JSON file first: `{}`
Then try again. If it does not work then print the JSONs contents and reply to this  answer so I can help you further.

Comment: The json files are not the problem, the problem is the code related to creating them, some files have content and other dont, I cant seem to get why thats happening

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered was in the function getJsonValues in the line

```
File = open(str(id)+'.json','w+')
```

Apparently 'w+' was messing with the file, making it empty every time i ran the function, changed it to 'r' as 'w+' wasn't necessary and it solved it. Thanks anyways